# jQuery trigger inside ES6 class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6

I´m struggling with a jQuery trigger inside an ES6 class. I can't figure out why this trigger is not working.

This is my class. The trigger should be executed when the triggerFilter method is called.

```js
// vendor import
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class SortingBar {
    constructor() {
        this.element = '[data-sortingBar]';
        this.sortOption = $(this.element).find('.sorting-bar__item');
        this.sortType = '';
        this.sortTypeInput = $(this.element).find('[name="sortType"]');
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        // early exit
        if ($(this.element).length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // trigger filter on sort option click
        this.sortOption.on('click', (e) => {
            this.triggerFilter(e.currentTarget);
        });
    }

    triggerFilter(element) {
        // avoid filter trigger for active sort option
        if ($(element).hasClass('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // set sort option value for hidden input
        this._setSortTypeInputValue(element);

        // trigger filter change
        this.sortTypeInput.trigger('change');
    }

    _getSortType(element) {
        this.sortType = $(element).data('sort-type');
        return this.sortType;
    }

    _setSortTypeInputValue(element) {
        this.sortTypeInput.val(this._getSortType(element));
    }
}
```

This module is imported in the main file like this

```js
// modules import
import Overlay from './modules/overlay';
import SortingBar from './modules/sorting-bar';

// modules init
const overlay = new Overlay();
const sortingBar = new SortingBar();


// modules object
const modules = {
    overlay,
    sortingBar
};

// modules object default export
export default {
    modules
};
```

There is also an old filter.js file in which the change event is binded to the hidden input which should be triggered. This file will be loaded before the main.js file.

```js
$('[name=selectWrapper], [name=sortType], [data-filters=reset]').on('change', refreshByChange);
```

I'm using webpack and babel-loader to compile the files to ES5. This is my Webpack config.

```js
// require
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// check node enviroment
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProd = (nodeEnv.trim() === 'production');

// default config settings
const config = {
    entry: {
        desktop: './src/main/js/thymeleaf_desktop/main_desktop.js'
        // mobile: './src/main/js/thymeleaf_phone/main_mobile.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main_[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'target/classes/js/thymeleaf_desktop')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};

// production config settings
if (isProd) {
    // eslint config settings
    const eslintConfig = {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|_externals|standalone)/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
            configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/build/eslint/webpack/.eslintrc')
        }
    };

    config.devtool = false;
    config.module.rules.push(eslintConfig);
    config.output.filename = 'main_[name].min.js';
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    );
}

module.exports = config;
```

The strange thing is, when I put the trigger in the main.js file everything is working just fine.

Is there a known issue for jQuery trigger inside an ES6 class?

Comment: No there is no issue with jQuery and `trigger` in es6 classes. There can be multiple reasons why this does not work for you. Have you verified that `triggerFilter` is called? Are you sure that `this.sortTypeInput.length` is not `0` before you call `this.sortTypeInput.trigger('change')`?

Comment: Yes, `triggerFilter` is called and also `this.sortTypeInput.length` is `1`. Everything else works for the hidden input. For example `this.sortTypeInput.remove();`

Comment: Then the problem might be the listener that listens for that `change` event.

Comment: Could you please do the following test. Add a `console.dir(this.sortTypeInput[0]);` right before or after the `this.sortTypeInput.trigger('change')`. Then open the developer tools of your browser, execute that code and look at the properties of that logged DOM Element. Right at the bottom of the property list you should see at least on entry `jQuery[a realy long number] : 1` do you see on or two of those entries? I would guess that for some reason there are multiple jQuery versions/instance active.

Comment: If your browser supports it you could write `console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.sortTypeInput[0]))`

Comment: Yes, there is an entry called `jQuery2130225834388266846541` and indead there are two jQuery versions loaded. One directly in the head and one from node_modules with `import $ from 'jquery`.

Head version: 2.1.3
Node Modules: 3.2.1

I gues I have to get rid off one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the jQuery trigger to native Javascript.

from:

`this.sortTypeInput.trigger('change');`

to:

`const event = new Event('change');
 document.getElementById('sortType').dispatchEvent(event);`

I don´t know why jQuery trigger is not working thow.

Comment: That does not really make sense. You are sure that `this.sortTypeInput.trigger('change')` worked before? Are you sure you listen to that event using `$('[name=selectWrapper], [name=sortType], [data-filters=reset]').on('change', refreshByChange);`, what you describe indicates that you use `addEventListener('change', ...` to listen to that event.

Comment: It´s really strange. `this.sortTypeInput.trigger('change')` will not trigger the event binded in the filter.js file.

However the native JS will trigger this event binding: `$('[name=selectWrapper], [name=sortType], [data-filters=reset]').on('change', refreshByChange);`

It doesn´t matter that the event binding is in another file, right?

I will continue investigating this today.

Answer (score 4):

Base on the comment the problem is that two instances of jQuery are used.

The `jQuery2130225834388266846541` tells you that the jQuery version `2.3.1` (the first three digits of the whole number, the other digits are the unique id of the instance)  was used to register the event listener.

`import $ from 'jquery';` includes the most likely the node module version (`3.2.1`)

The event triggering in jQuery does not use native events but an own event handling. You can only listen to events that are triggered by the same instance of jQuery that was used to register the even listeners (even if it is the same jQuery version), so you have to make sure that you only use one jQuery instance.

This is not only the case for event handling but also for `.data()`, because each instance of jQuery creates an own and isolated storage for data and even listeners. This can not only result in problems like the given one but also into memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem. I imported jquery in two different files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it came from the webpack context. Webpack create a copy of jquery so the event was triggered but in the wrong scope.

I deal with it by adding this line at the beggining of my code: `$ = window.$;`