# Trigger a JS custom event from a separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, jquery-events

I have a JS file that manage my popins. Each time a popin is opened or closed, I trigger a custom event like this.

**File n°1**

```js
$(document).trigger('popinOpen', {popin: $(popinId)});
```

Now if I want to do something when the trigger is fired, I can do the following.

**File n°2**

```js
$(document).on('popinOpen', function(e, popin) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(popin);
});
```

This code works when in the same file, but not in a separate file, and I don't understand why. I've tried moving the second file before or after the first one, but it does not change anything.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are triggering action before you start listening to it. 
When you divide your code in 2 different files you have to make sure, Your listener is registered first.

Include your listener first in your index.html and then the trigger action.

Comment: You're right ! I've tested with simple index.html and 2 Javascript files, and you have to listen to the action before triggering it. In my project, that's what I have, but it's still doesn't work. If I trigger it manually from the browser console, it works though. It must be specific to my project.

Comment: I manage my trigger with a bundled JS file with Webpack, while the file listening it is not. Looks more like a scope issue.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, even though my issue was not only a question of files order, it helps me to understand where was the "bug". It looks like Webpack and jQuery are not great friends when it comes to scoped variables. I had to use a plain Javascript solution to trigger and listen to my custom event to make it work, as (apparently) Webpack was using a different instance of jQuery than the one on my second file. More infos here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46404476/7160865